# Delphi 2009 TListView Change Grid Color and Width of GridLines

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-2009, gridlines, tlistview

I have a TListView with ViewStyle set to vsReport.  How do you change the color of the grid and the width of the gridlines.  The gridlines is a bit too thick in D2009, I want to have the same width as in D5.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any Delphi code that draws those lines. They're drawn by the underlying Windows common-control code, and that doesn't provide any means of specifying the thickness of the lines. They're either on or off. If you're seeing a different appearance between Delphi versions, then it's probably because you're running the program on different Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  However, is there a way to change the size of the cell as a cheat to reduce the size of the gridlines?  I have customDrawItem and customDrawSubItem to draw alternate rows of colors.